# How to put static resource image for input button?

Tags: visualforce

How to put static resource image for input button? I need to put image for `<input type="button"/>` call from Static Resource ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
<apex:commandButton style="background-image:url('{!$Resource.ButtonImageName}');width:100px;height:50px"/>
```

(or)

```
<style>
.buttonClass {
  background-image:url('{!$Resource.ButtonImageName}');
  width:100px;
  height:50px
}
</style>

<apex:commandButton styleClass="buttonClass"/>
```

Comment: i had used commandbutton. ineed to put for <input type="button" /> .

Comment: You can add it as <input type="button" class="buttonClass" />

Comment: i added class but image is not showing

Comment: Are you getting any error on browser's console tab ?

Comment: i am getting background white colour is showing.image is not showing.yes in browser console error is coming.image cannot be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using commandButton, then there is an image attribute which you can use. You can try below code.

`<apex:commandButton image = {!URLFOR($Resource.BackImg, 'coda2go/web/images/refresh.png')}/>`